# build opencv with ffmpeg support

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture

I read nearly all of the questions about this subject but I didn't solve it. I am working on Linux/Mint. I installed OpenCV in the virtual environment a lot of times when trying to solve this problem. Problem is that: **"cv2.videoCapture() return always false"**.

I built the OpenCV with **-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON** option and it would finish successfully and the result that about FFmpeg was like that: [image: ffmpeg result] It seemed to be OK.

Also, when I run "make -j8" command, it finished with no problem. So I thought everything will be OK. When I tried to check FFmpeg support with this command: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i FFmpeg` it gave me NO result.

I installed OpenCV with following [these steps.](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) 
I also tried to find if FFMPEG supports codec for decoding AVC encoded files. `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i avc` and, the output is :

> DEV.LS h264  H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264
>   h264_cuvid ) (encoders: h264_nvenc nvenc nvenc_h264 ) D.A.L. avc On2
>   Audio for Video Codec (decoders: on2avc )

I didn't understand why FFmpeg has seemed "YES" when I have building OpenCV at that time has given "NO" result with cv2.getBuildInformation().

```
(cv_env)➜  cv_env pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.2.0
(cv_env)➜  cv_env python                        
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'

(cv_env)➜  cv_env python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg
    FFMPEG:                      NO
(cv_env)➜  cv_env python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__file__
'/opt/cv_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so'

(cv_env)➜  cv_env python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'
>>> cv2.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-34m.so'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the "import cv2" is importing the cv you built and not some other, prebuilt, one? Try checking the version.

Comment: @Spikolynn I checked cv2.__version__ after import cv2, and it seems '3.3.0' also pip freeze result like that. I cloned OpenCV from github like these steps which I gave the url to my question. After following these steps, version should be 3.3.1 but it still seems 3.3.0. If I imported prebuilt opencv, how can I fix it? In my virtual env has just one OpenCV directory and I think it is the last one which I installed.

Comment: Are you running the code inside your virtual environment? As in do you activate the venv each time you run the python script?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yes, I installed opencv in the venv also it was activated.

Comment: /opt/cv_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages in this path contains opencv_python-3.3.0.10.dist-info directory and there aren't any thing about opencv. All steps for opencv installation finished without error but the site-packages has not any info about this installation.

Comment: Did you install for Python 2 or Python 3? How are you launching your python scripts?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I should tried both of them.  (cv_env)➜  cv_env find /usr/local/lib/ -type f -name "cv2*.so"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-34m.so
(cv_env)➜  cv_env find /opt/cv_env/local/lib/ -type f -name "cv2*.so"
/opt/cv_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so
/opt/cv_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-34m.so
/opt/cv_env/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2.cpython-34m.so
I hope you asked it.

Comment: How are you launching the scripts though? It sounds like you're launching Python 2, which has the other version of OpenCV installed, not 3.3.1.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yes, I launching python 2, I think I understand you. Well, how can I fix it? Can I change it or have I must reinstall opencv? And which commands depends on python2 or python3 when I install it? Sorry, I am very inexperienced in this subject.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I also tried it for python2 and python3 and both of them gave me the same result.  (cv_env)➜  cv_env python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not experienced in python, but I think you should somehow tell the import statement to use the cv that you built. Is this a cv2.pyc file that you made? Is it in the same folder that your project is?